# Using Nokogiri, how to convert html to text respecting block elements (ensuring they result in line breaks)

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

The Nokogiri [`#content`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#content-instance_method) method does not convert block elements into paragraphs; for example:

```
fragment = 'hell<span>o</span><p>world<p>I am Josh</p></p>'
Nokogiri::HTML(fragment).content
=> "helloworldI am Josh"
```

I would expect output:

```
=> "hello\n\nworld\n\nI am Josh"
```

How to convert html to text ensuring that block elements result in line breaks and [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements#Elements) are replaced with no space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `#before` and `#after` to add newlines:

```
doc.search('p,div,br').each{ |e| e.after "\n" }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
fragment = 'hell<span>o</span><p>world<p>I am Josh</p></p>'
HtmlToText.process(fragment)
=> "hello\n\nworld\n\nI am Josh"
```

I traverse the nokogiri tree, building a text string as I go, wrap the text in `"\n\n"` for block elements and `""` for inline elements. Then `gsub` to clean up the abundance of `\n` chars at the end. It's hacky but works.

```
require 'nokogiri'

class HtmlToText
  class << self
    def process html
      nokogiri = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
      text = ''
      nokogiri.traverse do |el|
        if el.class == Nokogiri::XML::Element
          sep = inline_element?(el) ? "" : "\n"
          if el.children.length <= 0
            text += "#{sep}"
          else 
            text = "#{sep}#{sep}#{text}#{sep}#{sep}"
          end
        elsif el.class == Nokogiri::XML::Text
          text += el.text
        end
      end
      text.gsub(/\n{3,}/, "\n\n").gsub(/(\A\n+)|(\n+\z)/, "")
    end

    private

    def inline_element? el
      el && el.try(:name) && inline_elements.include?(el.name)
    end

    def inline_elements
      %w(
        a abbr acronym b bdo big br button cite code dfn em i img input
        kbd label map object q samp script select small span strong sub
        sup textarea time tt var
      )
    end
  end
end
```